# Why do I get error (411) with submit_form (rvest)?

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I'm trying to use rvest to get some search results from a form on doleta.gov, but I'm getting an error on the forms on this page, and I can't figure out what I'm missing.

Here's an example:

```
library(rvest)
library(httr)
set_config( config( ssl_verifypeer = 0L ) )

num = "1234"
session <- html_session("https://www.doleta.gov/tradeact/taa/taa_search_form.cfm")
form <- html_form(session)[[2]]
form <- set_values(form, input = num)
results <- submit_form(session, form)
```

The final line returns a warning:

```
Submitting with 'NULL'
Warning message:
In request_POST(session, url = url, body = request$values, encode = request$encode,  :
  client error: (411) Length Required
```

What would I need to do to make this work on this page?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?